# How can WebRTC signaling state be saved on a server

Tags: webrtc, signaling

Recently I have read a article about [WebRTC in the real world](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/), it said that

> JSEP's architecture also avoids a browser having to save state: that is, to function as a     signaling state machine. This would be problematic if, for example, signaling data was lost each time a page was reloaded. Instead, signaling state can be saved on a server.

I know that WebRTC's signaling is based on state, such as **RTCpeerstate**, **RTCIceGatheringState**. Can someone explain to me that what exactly does the server need to do to save state?